# make emberjs event only get called once

Tags: ember.js

I have a app that has items that can contain child items and so on.

Each item has a mouseDown event that i want to be able to use to click and select an item.

The problem is that when i click a child item the parents mouseDown event is also being called.

How do i stop this so the mouseDown event only gets called once or if thats not posible i actually want the function called within the mouseDown event to only get called once.

Here is a jsfiddle to very simply show this. http://jsfiddle.net/rmossuk/W9vmW/1/

If you click no the Click here its mouse down event gets called twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `return false;` in the mouseDown function.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can you use event.stopPropagation(). I updated your fiddle, see http://jsfiddle.net/W9vmW/2/.

There is more informations about how event bubbling in ember works here - http://emberjs.com/guides/view_layer/#toc_event-bubbling

Events will bubble up the view hierarchy until the event reaches the root view. An event handler can stop propagation using the same techniques as normal jQuery event handlers:

return false from the method
event.stopPropagation